# Headset – sound, but no microphone – sound & microphone good on other computer

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sound-card, microphone, headset

Headset – sound, but no microphone – sound & microphone good on other computer

I plugged in a Logitech G230, and I got sound.

I could not get my microphone to work.

I tested the headset on another computer, and the microphone worked.

I tried updating the driver (Windows built-in driver search), but that didn’t work (had the newest).

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the driver, and restarted the computer.

When I plugged the headset in, the system tray showed an installation in progress.

After the installation, I noticed that the Controller Information in Microphone Properties and Speaker Properties showed Microsoft (don’t remember Microsoft being there before).

(Maybe it’s because I used Windows built-in driver search after an uninstall?)